# How much total data is on each node of a cluster?

Tags: cassandra, datastax

Within the context of the [lesson material](https://academy.datastax.com/courses/ds201-cassandra-core-concepts/internal-architecture-summary-and-review) for datastax, given this question:

> In a 3 node cluster with RF=2, how much total data volume does each
>   node own?

**How is this calculation made?**

I think I figured out a way to express this mathematically, but I consider my math skills to be poor, at best, and it makes at least one assumption -  that I'm not sure how to express verbally:

I can express it as a proportion:

node / data pct

The above example would look like this:

1 (node) / x (data pct) = 3 (nodes total) / 100% ( data pct )

3x = 100% ... x = 33.33% ( times the replication factor** ) = 66.66%

Thus, each node contains 2/3rds of the data.

** *This is the assumption that I'm aware of, that I can't articulate*

I'm looking for a sanity check: Does this method work to determine pct of data that each node owns, where 'data' is defined as all of the data added to cassandra by users? ( ie, not opscenter )

If so, does that mean on an 8-node cluster with RF=3, that each node contains 37.5% of the total data?

We had a loss of half of our servers in both of our dev c* data-centers and appear to have been able to recover all the data. I'm not sure how to verify this, but if each node did have 37.5% of the data, then it explains how we may have been able to fully recover: It would have meant that 150% of the data remained on the four nodes left over, assuming that replication had been set to RF=3 in both c* dc's. ( Which it was, for the data added by users. )

Answer (score 0):

Essentially yes your maths is correct. I think this is a simper way to express the same thing so it makes sense:

100% * RF = total amount of "unique data"

So (RF * 100%) / num_nodes = the amount of data on each node

For your example, 100% * 3/8 = 37.5% as you calculated.

It's true that if you sum the percentage of data owned on your remaining nodes and if it's less than 100% you will be missing data... but the converse is definitely not true. You can have ownership for remaining nodes be over 100% and still be missing some data, e.g. if all of the remaining nodes contain the exact same copies. So I don't think this is a good way to think about your resiliency.

If you are writing data to 3 nodes and you have 2 nodes go down, you know that there is still a copy of the data available. If 3 nodes go down, it is possible that there is some data that is unavailable (if it happens to be a primary node and the 2 replica nodes).